# Business Objects - Report Page Width (canvas?)

Tags: excel, report, width, business-objects

My automated pdf report, in Business Objects is too blinking wide, making my report span 2 pages, and also is 54 pages in total.

How do I change the width  - Report Page Width (canvas?) kind of like page breaks in Excel?

I'm using SAP BusinessObjects INFOVIEW through IE8

`The paper size and page orientation for printing can be different from the paper size and page orientation set for the reports when you view them in the Java Report Panel or Web Intelligence Rich Client. This enables users using different printers to specify the appropriate layout when they print.`

but no information about how to set the pages for pdf-ing.

Comment: i'm using SAP BUSINESSOBJECTS INFOVIEW through IE8

Comment: edit the question to enhance it

Comment: how do you mean?  I've put the platform, and the problem?  what else do you think i am missing?

Comment: If you can (and I've never used business objects), show how you are generating the report, is it via code or are you using a function. It might help so people can give additional options to try?

Comment: Its a standard report, using the the template table. There is no special code or formula behind it. It has 3 sets of tables running from queries. (pretty boring really)

Comment: Its not related to the report itself, just a general "how do i change the size of a report in infoview business objects" question

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions, depending on the version of SAP BusinessObjects you're using.

### **SAP BusinessObjects BI 4**

If you look in the toolbar under *Page Setup* > *Scale to Page* > *Width*, you'll be able to set the page width to 1 page. Web Intelligence will then scale the document's contents to fit everything on 1 page horizontally. You will still get several pages vertically, unless you configure *Page Height* as well. However I would leave that last setting on *automatic*, otherwise you may end up with a PDF with illegible content.

[image: Scale to page]

### **SAP BusinessObjects XI 3**

In this version, the situation is a little different and less self-explanatory.

Here, you have the setting *page size*, which enables you to select a page size for your document. Changing the page size determines how much Web Intelligence will be able to fit on one single page.

Example: if you have a default page size of A4, and notice that the content is split horizontally over two or more pages, you could increase the page size to A3 and check if everything will now fit on one page.

While it won't make a difference while working in Web Intelligence, it will when printing or exporting the document.

Say you have increased the size to A3, and you print your document on a printer with A4 pages. This means that the content will now be scaled to a smaller size in order to fit the contents on the A4 page.

If you export a document with a page size set to A3 to PDF, you'll notice that the pages are larger in the PDF and you'll need to zoom out further to see the whole page at once.

What it doesn't mean is that you'll need to print the document on A3 paper (you can if you want to, but you don't *have* to). This is often a misconception.

### Conclusion

The major difference between how you scale your document to a single page in XI 3.x and BI 4.x is while the latter will do it automatically, only requiring you to set the width once, in XI 3 you'll need to check for yourself if the chosen page size can accommodate the content and will need to re-check each time you make changes to your document that might affect this (e.g. add additional columns to your table).